# What is the max level?

Tags: puzzle-quest-2

What is the max level one can get to in [*Puzzle Quest 2*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puzzle_Quest_2)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dungeon goes down 6 levels, so 7 including the level you start on.

As for your character you can get up to level 50.  At 49 you get your last skill up, and 50 you get your last spell.